# How to print in Console Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, afnetworking

I am using afnetworking to parse JSON data. I want to print the data on the console.

How do i print this

```
self.videoMetaData = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video"];
```

i tried this

```
NSLog(@" data %@",videoMetaData);
```

it works when i have

```
NSArray *videoMetaData = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video"];
```

Comment: what is the problem? can't you `NSLog(@"%@", data)`?

Comment: Try `NSLog("%@", self.videoMetaData");` ?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40555154/5175709

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to use `NSLog(@" data %@", self.videoMetaData);` to log the data. There is no variable called `videoMetaData`.

Having said that, you might want to have a look how to examine objects and variables using the debugger. Have a look at this for example: http://www.cimgf.com/2012/12/13/xcode-lldb-tutorial/

There are some good videos on lldb from WWDC 2012 on developer.apple.com (you have to be a registered developer in the iOS or Mac Developer Program)