# How to print something to the console in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do you print something to the console of `Xcode`, and is it possible to view the `Xcode` console from the app itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

@Logan has put this perfectly. Potentially something worth pointing out also is that you can use

```
printf(whatever you want to print);
```

For example if you were printing a string:

```
printf("hello");
```

Comment: This is safer: `printf("%s", urVariableName);`

Comment: If the variable is `NSString`-type, then all I get from `printf()` is a gibberish pointer to the string.  And yet NSString still seems to be preferred to a char array in Objective-R, based on usage I've seen.

Answer (score 104):

How to print:

```
NSLog(@"Something To Print");
```

Or

```
NSString * someString = @"Something To Print";
NSLog(@"%@", someString);
```

For other types of variables, use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", someObject);
NSLog(@"%i", someInt);
NSLog(@"%f", someFloat);
/// etc...
```

Can you show it in phone?

Not by default, but you could set up a display to show you.

#### Update for Swift

```
print("Print this string")
print("Print this \(variable)")
print("Print this ", variable)
print(variable)
```

Comment: If there is a way, I haven't heard of it yet!

Comment: It didn't print on console, in my case. However, the printf alternative did.

Answer (score 22):

3 ways to do this:

In C Language (Command Line Tool) Works with Objective C, too:

```
printf("Hello World");
```

In Objective C:

```
NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
```

In Objective C with variables:

```
NSString * myString = @"Hello World";
NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

In the code with variables, the variable created with class, NSString was outputted be NSLog. The %@ represents text as a variable.

Answer (score 5):

@Logan said it perfectly. but i would like to add an alternative here,

> if you want to view logs from **just your application** then you can make
>   a **custom method** that keeps **saving the log to a file** in **`documents`
>   directory** & then you can view that log file from your application.

There is one good advantage for developers of the app after the app has been released & users are downloading it. Because your app will be able to send logs & crash reports to the developers (of course with the permissions of the device user !!!) & it'll be the way to improve your application.

Let me know (**To other SO users**), if there is another way of doing the same thing. (Like default Apple feature or something)

Let me know if it helps or you want some more idea.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use breakpoints. Assuming the value you want **is defined within the scope** of your breakpoint you have 3 options:

print it in console doing:

```
po some_paramter
```

Bare in mind in objective-c for properties you can't use self.

```
po _someProperty
po self.someProperty // would not work
```

po stands for print object.

---

**O**r can just use Xcode 'Variable Views' . See the image
[image]

I *highly* recommend seeing [Debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html) from Apple

---

**O**r just *hover* over within your code. Like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In some environments, NSLog() will be unresponsive.  But there are other ways to get output...

```
NSString* url = @"someurlstring";
printf("%s", [url UTF8String]);
```

By using `printf` with the appropriate parameters, we can display things this way.  This is the only way I have found to work on online Objective-C sandbox environments.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift** with **Xcode** you can use either `print()` or `NSLog()`.

`print()` just outputs your text. **Nothing more.**

`NSLog()` additionally to your text outputs time and other useful info to debug console.